# Errors from `ObjectSpace._id2ref`

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, objectid

What is the difference between the following two kinds of errors that `ObjectSpace._id2ref` returns?

```
0x... is recycled object (RangeError)

0x... is not id value (RangeError)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`not id value` means that there never was an object with that id.

`recycled object` means that there once was an object with that id, but it has been garbage collected.

Demo on Ruby 1.9.3/Ubuntu:

```
x = Object.new
id = x.object_id

puts "0x%x" % id
# => 0x4aef5e8

puts ObjectSpace._id2ref id
# => #<Object:0x95debd0>

x = nil

puts ObjectSpace._id2ref id
# => #<Object:0x95debd0>

GC.start

puts ObjectSpace._id2ref id
# => 0x4aef5e8 is recycled object (RangeError)
```

Note that the number in `Object#to_s` is *not* the `object_id` - according to the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-to_s) it is "an encoding of the object id".

Comment: I understand your explanation but do not understand your example. Why is the RangeError message showing a different object_id than the previous one?

Comment: Ah, yeah, I overlooked that, sorry. Updated accordingly.