# Ruby, how to fetch origin object by its memory address or by object_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, memory

For example, the address is "0x007f6f0954e820" string, how to get actual object?

I write these:
in GymsController

```
class GymsController < ApplicationController
  @@gyms = Array.new
  def private_page
    ...
    cookies.permanent[:gyms] = JSON.generate(@@gyms << @page)
  end
end
```

and in history.html.slim

```
- content_for :title, "History"
- breadcrumb :history
= stylesheet_link_tag 'application'

.outer
  main.privacy-index
    .content-wrapper
      h1.headline2 History一覧
      - JSON.parse(cookies.permanent[:gyms]).reverse.each do |value|
        = (value.to_s.split(":").last)[0..-2].inspect
        br
```

`(value.to_s.split(":").last)[0..-2].inspect` is "0x007f6f2b587b30"
But I wanna get real object, and do like `value.title`, `value.images`

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do??

Comment: @I wanna save an object array to cookies, like this: 
`cookies[:links] = JSON.generate(@array << @object)`
But when I do `JSON.parse(cookies[:links]).each do |value|`, I get some address string. I actually wanna get origin objects.

Comment: Can you show what you have and what you want to fetch from it?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I have that object's obejct_id and its address which is a string.
I want to get its origin object.

Comment: Do you mind adding actual values to the question?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Yeah, I have already done this.

Comment: Here `(value.to_s.split(":").last)[0..-2].inspect`, what does `value` return?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh return "0x007f6f2b587b30", cry~~~~, I wanna it returns its origin object.

Comment: No, the value of `(value.to_s.split(":").last)[0..-2].inspect` is "0x007...", but what is the value of variable `value`? Even before the whole chain of methods is called on it.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh `value` is <#:0x007f6f2b587b30>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know a way to "get" the Object by **memory address** (i.e. your `0x007f6f2b587b30`),

but you can "get" the Object by **`object_id`** using `ObjectSpace._id2ref(OBJECT_ID)`:

### Solution:

*Important: this still has inherit issues: see my recommendations below why.*

**app/controllers/gyms_controller.rb:**

```
class GymsController < ApplicationController
  @@gyms = Array.new
  def private_page
    ...
    gym = @page
    @@gyms << gym
    cookies.permanent[:gyms_object_ids] = gym.object_id
  end
end
```

**your view file:**

```
- content_for :title, "History"
- breadcrumb :history
= stylesheet_link_tag 'application'

.outer
  main.privacy-index
    .content-wrapper
      h1.headline2 History一覧
      - cookies.permanent[:gyms_object_ids]).reverse.each do |gym_object_id|
        - gym = ObjectSpace._id2ref(gym_object_id.to_i)
        = gym.title
        = gym.images
        br
```

### Recommendations:

- use "class instance-variable" `@gyms` instead of "class class-variable" `@@gyms`. See why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802540/difference-between-class-variables-and-class-instance-variables).
- if your `@page` variable above in your controller, is not a record (being that it does not correspond to any of the models you have, and thus is not saved in the DB), then create a model for it, so that you can save it into the DB, and retrieve these data in your views above through the model's record `id`, and therefore no longer by `object_id`.

  This would allow you to solve the following issues of my Solution
  above:

  - Objects reside in memory, and are subject to garbage collection. Therefore using `ObjectSpace._id2ref(OBJECT_ID)` is probably gonna fail at times if the Object is already garbage-collected. ([see this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508536/errors-from-objectspace-id2ref)), because `ObjectSpace._id2ref` above in my solution code runs at different code of execution than where the object is originally defined:

    - one is in the controller where `@page` object is defined (some request1 / say thread1),
    - the other one is in the view file where `ObjectSpace._id2ref()` tries to get that object (some request2 / say thread2),
  - in your code, you are using `@@gyms = Array.new`, which means that `@@gyms` (being stored in-memory) is not gonna be accessible to other rails processes because memory is not shared between these processes, and to put simply means that `@@gyms` would have **DIFFERENT!** values for each of the following processes:

    - rails server #1 (say... unicorn-1 in server1)
    - rails server #2 (say... unicorn-2 in server1)
    - rails server #3 (say... unicorn-3 in server2)
    - background worker process #1 (say... sidekiq-1)
    - background worker process #2 (say... sidekiq-2)
    - etc...

    ...whereas if you instead save the `gyms` (if possible and if necessary only) into a model and that these gym records belong to a user, then I would imagine doing something like below instead (which will solve these potential differing values above, and will no longer require you to use cookies):

    ```
    class Gym < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :gyms_users
      has_many :users, through: :gyms_users
    end

    class GymsUser < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :gym
      belongs_to :user
      validates :user, uniqueness: { scope: :gym }
    end

    class User < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :gyms_users
      has_many :gyms, through: :gyms_users
    end
    ```

Comment: You are awesome!

Comment: No prob! Glad to help! :3